# Is there something in Kohana similar to CakePHP's requestAction?

Tags: php, cakephp, kohana

I have taken over a Kohana project that needs some modifications. It doesn't really seem to follow the conventional MVC patterns (at least what I've learned from CakePHP). I need to do some dirty hacks to get data from a controller within a view which I would use $this->requestAction(...) in CakePHP.

My question is, is there anything similar in Kohana that will return the results of a controller's action?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the Kohana guide *[Views and HTML](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/using.views)*. If that's not what you're looking for then ...

You can also do sub-requests in Kohana 3 using it's HMVC features.

```
$response = Request::factory('URL')->execute()->response;
```

That internally calls the URL and returns the output (as it normally would in the browser).

Answer (score 1):

Within a controller :

```
$this->request->response = View::factory('some_view_file')
->set(array(
'some_var' => $some_value,
'other_var' => $other_value,
));
```

Than, in the some_view_file, you can call it with `$some_var`. Everything must be passed to a view file, it should never contain any application logic.

If you still don't get it, you should ask yourself do you really understand php5 oop & (h)mvc pattern :)